# how can I fix this CRUD issue

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee

How can I fix this hibernate issue please? I'm trying to use dao pattern but I get this stack trace as a result :

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.dom4j.DocumentException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at com.forum.utils.HibernateUtils.<clinit>(HibernateUtils.java:15)
at com.forum.dao.UtilisateurDAO.create(UtilisateurDAO.java:19)
at com.forum.form.InscriptionForm.inscrireUtilisateur(InscriptionForm.java:68)
at com.forum.servlets.Inscription.doPost(Inscription.java:29)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

It triggers from this line :

> Session s = HibernateUtils.getSession();

Comment: It looks like 's' may be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure all hibernate dependencies are satisfied.
 http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.dom4j.DocumentException